# include файла со стороннего сервера (домена) - 500 ошибка

Tags: php

С одного домена пытаюсь получить обработанные данные с другого домена.
include работает но данные получить не могу, открывается белая страница - 500 ошибка.
В подключаемом php файле, примерно следующее содержимое - функции:

```
protected function getVideo($id){
$part = "snippet,statistics";
$this->url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key={$this- >config["key"]}&part=$part&videoEmbeddable=true&videoSyndicated=true&id=$id";
$data = $this->http(TRUE);
$data->items[0]->snippet->description = nl2br($data->items[0]->snippet->description);
if ($this->badwords($data->items[0]->snippet->title)==true) {
header("Location: {$this->config["url"]}");
exit;
}
return $data->items[0];
}
```

php.ini настроил
 из-за чего может появляться 500 ошибка? 
Как добиться того, чтобы домен А подключал php с функциями с домена Б и выводил результат на домене А?
Спасибо!

Comment: что вы хотите сделать? Получаете статистику по видео из google API ?

Comment: да, статистика + само видео - id

Comment: сайтов десяток, нужно их все запитать на один файл с функциями который лежит на другом домене

Comment: А где include в вашем коде из вопроса?

Comment: Домен А,     include ("https://сайт.ру/includes/Youtube.class.php"); <br /> include php с текстом отображает, с функциями 500 ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить более оптимальный код получения статистики для видео,попробуйте так:

> Код запроса

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics%2Csnippet&id=UCMGgBRBiijmpgL3xNuiDVOQ&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

> Ответ (приблизительно)

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/u91Ip901f5gugoIao8qNyVWT260\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {


   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/Dz1xACW2UlE83duQRwtwzvHayHM\"",
   "id": "UCMGgBRBiijmpgL3xNuiDVOQ",
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Vecci87",
    "description": "",
    "publishedAt": "2008-11-07T02:20:17.000Z",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-TQMNhxH839s/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/mwbxvegAUXk/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-TQMNhxH839s/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/mwbxvegAUXk/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-TQMNhxH839s/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/mwbxvegAUXk/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     }
    },
    "localized": {
     "title": "Vecci87",
     "description": ""
    }
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "8718115",
    "commentCount": "275",
    "subscriberCount": "60995",
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
    "videoCount": "36"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Приблизительно это я и получаю, проблема не в этом. Данный результат мне нужно получить на домене А в то время, когда сама функция лежит на домене Б. Что-то типа защиты кода от распространения на любителя... Т.е. код на домене Б "эксклюзивный"

Comment: Для этого вы должны написать маленький API код на домене А  который методом CURL будет обращатся на домен Б (по определённому URL). На домене Б, функция при получении запроса от домена А делает отдельный запрос к google API и полученный ответ передаёт CURL , который в свою очередь возвращает ответ на домен А. Полного готового ответа в виде всего кода тут вряд ли можно дать, а вот каких то include вам точно не нужно!